# How do I apply Bernoulli's equation in a rotating frame of reference?

Tags: bernoulli-equation

I intend to apply Bernoulli's equation in an annular swirl flow where v_z is constant, omega_z is dependent on radial location. I need to apply the Bernoulli's equation in a reference frame rotating at an angular velocity of omega_prime. How should I go about it?

P.S.: v_z is the axial velocity, omega_z is the angular velocity.